# Netplan wasn't applied

Tags: networking, netplan

I edited netplan yaml file in the `/etc/netplan` directory to set static ip on `ens1f0` interface.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 163.239.14.35/24
      gateway4: 163.239.14.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [163.239.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
        search: []
    ens1f0:
      addresses:
      - 172.16.10.7/12
      gateway4: 172.16.10.1
    ens1f1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

However, Netplan doesn't applied even though I ran 'netplan apply' command.
`ifconfig` tells me that ip on ens1f1 was not applied.

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 163.239.14.35  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 163.239.14.255
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fed9:17ea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:d9:17:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 214589  bytes 265226422 (265.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2757  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49502  bytes 4862456 (4.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfb120000-fb13ffff

ens1f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 90:e2:ba:c4:67:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens1f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 90:e2:ba:c4:67:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`netplan --debug apply` shows me some error-like messages as below.

```
DEBUG:ens1f0 not found in {'eno1': {'addresses': ['163.239.14.35/24'], 'gateway4': '163.239.14.1', 'nameservers': {'addresses': ['163.239.1.1', '8.8.8.8'], 'search': []}}}
DEBUG:ens1f1 not found in {'eno1': {'addresses': ['163.239.14.35/24'], 'gateway4': '163.239.14.1', 'nameservers': {'addresses': ['163.239.1.1', '8.8.8.8'], 'search': []}}, 'ens1f0': {'addresses': ['172.16.10.7/12'], 'gateway4': '172.16.10.1'}}
```

What could be the problem? I spent total weekend to solve this problem.

os version: ubuntu 20.04 (server)

Comment: Hi JungHwanPark, welcome. Are the interfaces ens1f0 and ens1f1 connected and the link is up? please edit your question and add the output of ip a to your question. Please add the Ubuntu Version you use (including Deskop or Server), too.

Comment: The debug output suggests that you may have indentation problems in your config file.  Your paste here looks correct, but you may want to double-check that `eno1`, `ens1f0`, and `ens1f1` are all at the same indentation level, with spaces not tabs.

Comment: An unrelated issue is that you are trying to use multiple `gateway4` declarations.  This is not going to work.  You should use `routes` with routing tables instead if you have multiple upstream Internet connections.  If only one interface gives you a route to the Internet, that interface should have the gateway.

Comment: @dummyuser Can you explain the meaning of 'output of ip'? And I supplment info of os version.